# Why do some words exist in British English but not American English?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Thinking about the word "rubbish" which is widely used in the UK while non-existent in the USA, how do such words surface in Britain but not America?

I read somewhere that American English is closer to British English 300 years ago than British English today itself is. How does one explain this? Did English continue to evolve based on borrowing words from other European languages while America remained isolated? How big a role did British writers/poets that were popular only domestically play? Did technology entrepreneurs coin local words simultaneously (motorway, lorry)? I know there were language steering committees in America in the late 1700s but I doubt they would have abandoned words like "rubbish" for being too obscene as they did for some other words.

I know you can encapsulate the whole chaos in the term "culture" but this seems merely like a sophisticated way of saying "there was no systematic force, it was just chance" which isn't really insight.

Note I'm not focusing on terms that are more common in America than Britain. I'm talking specifically about British-only words.

Other words: autumn, knackered, nappy

EDIT - Those who can't answer but are finding entertainment in this can find more examples here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_British_terms_not_widely_used_in_the_United_States
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_having_different_meanings_in_American_and_British_English:_M%E2%80%93Z

Comment: I (AmE speaker) think that your theory is *rubbish*.  While we say *garbage* or *trash* instead of *rubbish* when speaking about the stuff we put in the *trash cans/garbage cans* (not *dustbins or rubbish bins*) we still use the word rubbish for other things.

Comment: Fair enough, but you get my wider question don't you? I'm just trying to make the question more tangible with an example.

Comment: Autumn is certainly also used. Knackered and nappy not so much.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat Speak to me of these late 18th century "steering committees."

Comment: "Autumn" is certainly used in the US, though "fall" is more common.  "Knackered", I'll admit, is not used, but why would we even want another word for "diaper"?

Comment: I'm not suggesting diaper is an inferior term. I'm asking what geosocial forces make some words (almost) British-only?

Comment: And with regard to "nappy", perhaps you'd like to explain why those crazy Brits invented a new word ca 1920 when the perfectly good word "diaper" has existed since the 1500s.

Comment: @ Sridhar-Samobat: The last sentence of your last comment is the core of a reasonable question.  Whether it has been asked before here, I don't know.

Comment: I must admit, I did not know diapers existed in the 1500s.

Comment: There's something wrong with this whole question.

Comment: I think you’ve answered your own question. "Culture" encompasses psychology, sociology, economy; in fact, most of the humanities. I think each word would need to be evaluated individually, and even then we probably wouldn’t approach a generalized theory for why some words took off and some didn't. Conversely, I am sure we could find [many examples of Americanisms that haven't made it to the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_American_terms_not_widely_used_in_the_United_Kingdom).

Comment: Is it so astonishing that language areas that are 6000 km and more apart develop differences?  In the area where I grew up the people in the next village, only one km away, pronounced some words differently. Language has the natural tendency to diverify.

Comment: @HotLicks Really? You pronounce "gar-Bahj" like, say, *ga-Rahj?" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/garbage?s=t

Comment: @Elian - More or less.  Only drag out the second syllable a bit, French style.  And I always keep my pinkie finger elevated as I say it.

Comment: @Elian - Yes and no.  It's the pronunciation I use about half the time.  It makes some people smile -- others give me strange looks.  (But I'm no stranger to strange looks.)

Comment: Yet another case of stack exchange naysayers and put down artists masquerading as experts.

Comment: I got a good answer from a colleague. One example of localized force that pulls the languages apart is "pharmacy". Originally it meant the little counter where you get medicine, even in the USA. While the British still use it this way, American pharmacies had so much land that the pharmacy companies diversified to make them full retail stores (which the British call "drugstores").

Comment: And just to state the other part which rogermue hinted at but didn't really make explicit - language is constantly evolving due to convenience (which is why words like `u` and `sms` will eventually make it into the dictionary). Evolution cannot be perfectly replicated (same way a human hand can't draw a perfect copy of a picture), so you get divergence. Still, I'd like to know with examples some of the actual forces (apart from technology) that shape language.

Comment: 'which the British call "drugstores" ' - er, the _Americans_ call 'drugstores', and the British generally call 'Chemists'

Comment: Thankfully now that ChatGPT exists, I can get answers to the spirit of my question instead of an avalanche of intellectual masturbation.

Answer (score 4):

I think your Question needs to be rethought, as many of the comments indicate.  See especially the comment from rogermue.

To me, the opposite of your Question might be more interesting.  Why, in spite of an ocean, have British English and American English remained so close?  (This may have already been discussed on ELU).

I scanned the list you added, and a large fraction of the words were familiar, although not ones I routinely use or hear.

Two of your assertions seem doubtful to me: (1) "there were language steering committees in the US in the late 1700s" and (2) "American English is closer to British English 300 years ago than British English today itself is."

(1) As deadrat said, "Speak to me of these late 18th century steering committees." If they existed at all (references ?), were they more than a few academics briefly holding forth?

(2) It is often stated that English as spoken in the more remote parts of Appalachia is close to 18th century English, but I have never seen this statement made about American English in general. And, going back to rogermue's comment, the English of the Deep South is not the English of Brooklyn or of New Hampshire or of Los Angeles.

Comment: I think it was either mother tongue or made in America by Bill Bryson. It's a bit difficult to go back and find the quote without spending hours going through so many pages. And when I make these observations to colleagues or friends their reaction is basically one of me just telling them what they already know. So I assumed people interested enough in the question would have done their own research or kept quiet.